# What fittings do I need to connect this filter to my sink waterline?

Tags: plumbing, fitting, water-filtration

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I have little experience in plumbing and don't want to use the wrong parts.

I'm trying to plumb a European espresso machine to my under-sink faucet water line, with a water filter in the middle. I believe the cold waterline has a standard 3/8" valve. I need to connect it to this under-sink [water filter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0087E6N2U), whose [spec sheet](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Cm2umUI8L.pdf) states *"Inlet and outlet plumbing connections are 3/8” FNPT"*. The espresso machine has a 1/8" *BSP* inlet connection.

Here is my current cold water valve:
[image]

And here is my hot water valve, which seems to already have a 3-way fitting installed to feed something else (but I don't know what it's called):
[image]

I'm trying to figure out:

1. What's the exact part name for the 3-way fitting that would work here?
2. What kind of hose would work to go from the 3-way fitting to the water filter linked above?
3. What kind of hose would work to go from the water filter to the espresso machine, which has 1/8" BSP thread?

Any other tips on installing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3/8" female NPT is relatively common.  You're connecting this filter to your cold water supply valve—correct?  Your supply valve is likely 3/8" male compression.  So you need a hose and/or fitting to connect that to the 3/8" NPT port on your filter.  Probably get a fitting like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/LTWFITTING-3-8-in-O-D-Comp-x-3-8-in-MIP-Brass-Compression-Adapter-Fitting-25-Pack-HF686625/313501941 (except you don't need 25 of them!) and thread it into your filter.  Connect supply and filter with a double 3/8" compression supply hose.

If your supply valve isn't 3/8" compression you'll need yet another adapter.

For the other end, you'll need a way to adapt the 3/8" NPT to your 1/8" BSP.  You don't say whether the latter is male or female, so...